# How to disable multiple given buttons at once

Tags: java, android

I have to disable 7 buttons in case 1 and 3 buttons in case 2. I am trying to make a single function to disable buttons in both the case. In both the cases, I'll pass an array containing `IDs` of buttons to be disabled to function.
Example:-

```
Case:1
String [ ] arrayString = {"btn1", "btn2", "btn3", "btn4", "btn5", "btn6", "btn7"};

Case:2
String [ ] arrayString = {"btn1", "btn2", "btn3"};
```

Function:-

```
private void disable buttons(String[ ] buttons){

}
```

Now the problem is that I don't know what to do next. I made it till here but I don't know what should I do next. Please help me.

Comment: loop the buttons array of string and use findViewById() function to get the Button and do whatever you want to do with it. In your case disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the id of any `View` by its "name":

```
public void disableButtons(String[] buttonNames) {
    for (String name : buttonNames) {
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(id);
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

If this code will not be used inside an activity, then you will have to supply a valid Context like this:

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", context.getPackageName());
```

So you can call:

```
disableButtons(arrayString);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you want to enable/disable multiple buttons at once you could store them in a list and then simply iterate

```
lateinit var buttons: List<Button>
onCreate(...) {
    //after the layout is inflated add all buttons to the list
    buttons = listOf(button1, button2, button3)
}
...
buttons.forEach { it.enabled = false }
```

As an alternative, you could access all buttons on the screen by recursively going through display list hierarchy. First, we need this two kotlin extensions:

```
var View.enabledRecursive
        get() = isEnabled
        set(value) {
            isEnabled = value
            if (this !is ViewGroup) return
            children.forEach { it.isEnabledRecursive = value }
        }

val ViewGroup.children
    get() = (0 until childCount).map { getChildAt(it) }
```

then just call it on parent layout or some container containing all the buttons

```
parentLayout.enabledRecursive = true
```